# PendingIntent not working except firsttime

Tags: android, kotlin

i have foreground service and show STICKY notification.

the notification has two button and i set click listener both of buttons

the pending intent implemented like this

```
private fun getClickPendingIntent1(context: Context): PendingIntent {
val schemeString = "scheme://~~whatever"

return PendingIntent.getActivity(
context,
0,
Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(schemeString)),
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE else PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
)
}




private fun getClickPendingIntent2(context: Context): PendingIntent {
val schemeString = "scheme://~~whatever2"

return PendingIntent.getActivity(
context,
0,
Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(schemeString)),
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE else PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
)
}
```

if i click button 1 and pendingintent1 called, my app is started. but after starting app, button 1 and pendingintent1 is not working anymore. but button2 and pendingintent2 is still working every time i clicked it.

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The request code shall be unique for each different pending intent:

`PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, ...)`

`PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, ...)`

Comment: Should make no difference here as the underlying `Intent`s are different (data is different). But let's see what OP says about your suggestion.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it didn't work... once a pendingintent start my app, the rest calls of same pendingintent are not starting my launcher activity.

Comment: what's the Activity launcher implementation moethinds like onCreate, onNewIntent? maybe you have additional setup in AndroidManifest.xml Acitivty config?